# Populate an empty matrix with values after comparing column and row in R

Tags: r, matrix, multiple-columns

Can I ask you how do I with the R language compare a table (attributes: starting machine name, target machine name and incremental id) and an empty matrix (where we have the target machine name in the columns and the starting machine name in the rows ). If there is a match between the start and finish then I want to compile with the incremental id value within the array.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9vPnw.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9TcoA.png)

I expect that inside the array is incremental id

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It would be nice if you can provide a reproducible example (https://reprex.tidyverse.org/). Based on your images, I assumed that your dataset look like this one:

```
machine_table <- data.frame(
  incremental_id = rep(1:2, times=5),
  start_machine = paste0("A", 1:5),
  target_machine = factor(c("A1", "A2"), levels = paste0("A", 1:5))
)

machine_table
```

To create your matrix you have multiple possibilities, here you will first filter the row with a matching start and target machine before pivoting and converting to a matrix.

First, convert the machine columns to factors as we already know them.

```
machine_table$start_machine <-  factor(machine_table$start_machine, levels = paste0("A", 1:5))
machine_table$target_machine <- factor(machine_table$target_machine, levels = paste0("A", 1:5))
```

Then select only the rows where the machines match and pivot the pivot and expand with unmatched machine names. You can use `machine_table` instead of `match` in `pivot_wider` to do the same operation on the whole dataset.

```
match <- machine_table[machine_table$start_machine == machine_table$target_machine, ]
match_table <- tidyr::pivot_wider(match, 
                   id_cols = "start_machine",  id_expand = T,
                   names_from = "target_machine", names_expand = T,
                   values_from =  "incremental_id")
```

After that you only need to convert this table to a matrix, and renames the rows

```
machine_matrix <- as.matrix(match_table[, -1])
row.names(machine_matrix) <- match_table$start_machine
machine_matrix
```

If you have multiple value for one pair of machine you can specify an aggregating function like min, max, sd, etc. as `values_fn` argument in `pivot_wider`.

EDIT:
Based on you comment, here is an approach with a for loop, looping through all the rows and columns of the matrix and row of the dataframe.

```
for (i in seq(nrow(tabellaMatrice))) {
  for (j in seq(ncol(tabellaMatrice))) {
    for (r in seq(nrow(tab2))) {
      ifelse(tab2$Da[r]==rownames(tabellaMatrice)[i] & tab2$A[r]==colnames(tabellaMatrice)[j],
             tabellaMatrice[i,j] <- tab2$`Numero incrementale`[r],
             NA
      )
    }
  }
}
```

If there is multiple values for the same machine pair, the last value in the dataframe will erase the other ones.

Comment: Sorry, but doesnt' work. I'm trying to do this part with a cycle for:

Comment: for (i in nrow(rownames(tabellaMatrice))) {
  for (j in ncol(colnames(tabellaMatrice))) {
    for (r in nrow(tab2$Da)) {
      ifelse(tab2$Da[r]==rownames(tabellaMatrice)[i],
             for (o in nrow(tab2$A)) {
               ifelse(tab2$A[o]==colnames(tabellaMatrice),
                      for (p in nrow(tab2$`Numero incrementale`)) {
                        tabellaMatrice[i,j]<-tab2$`Numero incrementale`[p]
                        
                      }
                      ,"")
               
             },"")
      
    }
    
  }
  
}

Comment: I added another solution to my answer. It's based on your code with some simplifications and corrections.